# How to make a thread wait for a condition to perform an operation without it using too much CPU time?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've been trying to use threads in a matrix operation to make it faster for large matrixes (1000x1000). I've had some sucess so far with the below code. With significant speed improvements in comparision to using a single thread.

```
void updateG(Matrix &u, Matrix &g, int n, int bgx, int tamx, int tamy) 
{
int i, j;

for (i = bgx; i < tamx; i += n)
 {
    for (j = 0; j < tamy; j++)
    {
        g(i,j, g(i,j)+ dt * 0.5 * (u(i,j) - (g(i,j) * y)));
    }
 }
}
void updateGt(Matrix &u, Matrix &g, int tam)strong text
{
 int i;
 const int n = NT;
 std::thread array[n];
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
    array[i] = std::thread(updateG, std::ref(u), std::ref(g), n, i, tam, tam);
 }
 joinAll(array, n);
}
```

However, I need to call this operation several times in the main code, and every time this happens, I must initialize the thread array again, creating new threads and wasting a lot of time (according to what I've read online those are expensive).
So, I've developed an alternative solution to create and initialize the thread array only once, and use the same threads to perform the matrix operations every time the function is called. Using some flag variables so the thread only performs the operation when it has to. Like in the following code:

```
  void updateG(int bgx,int tam)
  {
    while (!flaguGkill[bgx]) {
        if (flaguG[bgx]) {
            int i, j;

            for (i = bgx; i < tam; i += NT)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < tam; j++)
                {
                    g->operator()(i, j, g->operator()(i, j) + dt * 0.5 * (u->operator()(i, j) - (g->operator()(i, j) * y)));
                }
            }
            flaguG[bgx] = false;

        }
    }
  }

 void updateGt()
 {
    
    for (int k = 0; k < NT; k++)
    {
        flaguG[k] = true;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NT; i++)
    {
        while(flaguG[i]);
    }
   }
```

My problem is. This solution, that's supposed to be faster, is much slower than the first one, by a large margin. In my complete code, I have 2 functions like this updateGt and updateXt, and I'm using 4 threads for each, I believe the problem is that while the function is supposed to be idle waiting, it is instead using a lot of CPU time only to keep checking on the codition. Anyone knows if that is really the case, and if so, how could I fix it?

Comment: [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Comment: You must use `std::mutex`, and `std::condition_variable`. In its current state, the shown code is undefined behavior and it's only a matter of time before it breaks horribly.

Comment: Why not use OpenMP instead?

Comment: @mpoeter Never studied it before, this is my first experiment with threads, for what I've just read it is an api to implement concurrency in an easier way, right? If that's the I might try that next if this approach doesn't work at all.

Comment: @AlanBirtles SamVarshavchik Thank you for the tip, gonna get some reading on these topics. And surprisingly it does not break, and the output result it's the same as other versions of the code, it's just wayy slower.

Comment: Yes, OpenMP is a simple way to parallelize stuff. It is a separate standard and independent of C++, but most popular C/C++ compiler support it. It is perfectly suited for your use case - you simply have to annotate your loop as parallel for loop.

Comment: However, if you really want to build your own solution (for practice), what you are looking for is called a _barrier_, i.e., a construct that blocks the threads until all threads have reached the barrier. Unfortunately, C++ does not yet provide a built-in barrier (this will be part of C++20). So you either have to create your own version, or take one from GitHub (e.g. https://github.com/nipuntalukdar/cyclicbarrier).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is called [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). As mentioned in comments you'll want to use [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), like this:

```
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;
```

---

```
while (!flaguGkill[bgx]) {
    {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex); // aquire mutex lock as required by condition variable
    cv.wait(lock, [this]{return flaguG[bgx];}); // thread will suspend here and release the lock if the expression does not return true
    } 

    int i, j;
    
    for (i = bgx; i < tam; i += NT)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < tam; j++)
        {
            g->operator()(i, j, g->operator()(i, j) + dt * 0.5 * (u->operator()(i, j) - (g->operator()(i, j) * y)));
        }
    }
    flaguG[bgx] = false;
    
}
```

Note: the section `[this] { return flaguG[bgx];}`, you may need to alter the capture paramaters (the bit in the `[]`) depending on the scope of those variables

Where you set this to be true, you then need to call

```
for (int k = 0; k < NT; k++)
{
    flaguG[k] = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}

// you can then use another condition variable here
```

Comment: Thank you, that proved to work! I don't know why thoug, it is still considerably slower than the first code, is it suppose to be, considering everything else equal? Or maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: It probably locks the mutex longer than it needs to making your application essentially single threaded

Comment: Yes, sorry, You might want to change how long the mutex is held (it's [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) so you can just move the scope bracket up).

Comment: That was it! explicitly unlocking the mutex lock after the wait fixed it! Thank you all!

Comment: Good to hear, silly of me not to do that initially. Answer updated so as to be useful to anyone else